# At each vertex of a convex polyhedron P, n faces converge, and they are all arbitrary m-gons (not necessarily regular). Find the number of edges of P.

Tags: geometry

At each vertex of a convex polyhedron P, n faces converge,and they are all arbitrary m-gons (not necessarily regular). Find the number of edges of P.

I know about Euler's theorem. And I know that in the case of a regular polyhedron, the formula $nV=2E$ works, where $n$ is the number of faces that meet, $E$ is the number of edges, and $V$ is the number of vertices. But how do I combine all this and find the number of edges for the General case?

Comment: Hint: $nV = 2E = \color{red}{mF}$

Comment: And achille hui's formulas hold for *any* polyhedron where every vertex has $n$ faces (and therefore $n$ edges) and every face has $m$ sides, not just regular polyhedra. They are the resulf of a basic counting exercise: $nV$ is the sum of the number of edges at each vertex, which counts every edge twice, and $mF$ is the sum of the number of edges around each face, which also counts every edge twice.